# Submit form with button input and jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, button, submit

I have a form like this :

```
<form id="myform" action="something.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="first_name" /><br />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I want to submit this form after getting successful message from some processes in JavaScript and jQuery. So I did it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.post('process/process.php',
          {
              // I passed data here
          },
          function(data) {
              if (data.result == '1') {
                  $('#myform').submit();
              } else {
                  alert('Error #'+data.result+' occurred!');
              }
          },
          'json'
    );
  });
});
```

But even after getting `data.result == '1'`, the submitting form does not work. What's the problem here ?

---

**Edit:**

I've changed jQuery to :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#submit').click(function(event){
    $('#myform').submit();
  )};
)};
```

So there is no condition now, but form did not submit.

Comment: Are you sure it returns '1' and not 1?

Comment: @meWantToLearn I did it , you can watch it in my codes.

Comment: Are you sure that $('#myform') was found?

Comment: maybe console.log or alert $('#myform').length before the submit then - it should be 1 (not 0 and not more than 1 ;-)

Comment: @m7o I changed IF condition with `data.result == 1 || data.result == '1'` and again no submitting occurred!

Comment: As you said before you already put an alert before $('#myform').submit(); so that seems to be called - now I'd check if $('#myform') is found at all or if maybe the id is used twice on the page

Comment: $('#myform').length shows you how often $('#myform') exists in the dom

Comment: try to run $('#myform').submit(); from console :)

Comment: @Arkady I did it. An error occurred: TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function

Comment: On a further note, with this code users will still be able to submit the form normally by pressing enter when in an input field so it might not be an optimal approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the jQuery [documentation for `.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/),

> Additional Notes:
>
> Forms and their child elements **should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit,** length, or
>   method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete
>   list of rules and to check your markup for these problems, see
>   DOMLint.

Rename the id of the second input to `submitForm` or something similar.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WvSdX/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of a value-comparison issue here.
to give us a better way to determine if this is the case, can you temprorly change the callback to this and give it a try?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#submit').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      $.post('process/process.php',
          {
              // I passed data here
          },
          function(data) {
               $('#myform').submit();   
          },
          'json'
    );
  });
});
```

if the form get submitted, then there is nothing wrong with the jQuery part, it's a matter of correctly getting the result out of your post() operation.

Please give it a try and let me know if it's working or not.

Comment: I did it Mohammed. I insterted `submit()` just after `.click(function()){` and again the form did not submit.

Comment: Mohammed I put `submit()` after `$(document).ready()` and I expected that form must be sent, but nothing happened!

Comment: so weird!!
I think you will have to check the console result (in firebug or chrome developer tools) because this may mean that there is an error in the page itself, not with the code you are writing.

Comment: if you can provide the code for your page, we may create a sample in JsFiddle.com and see what's going on.

Comment: Which chrome plugin do you suggest for this ?

Comment: no plugin is needed, just hit "F12" and the firebug-like panel should show up.

Comment: when it does, reload your page, and let me know what is being written inside the "Console" window.